# Simple Addition

Tags: riddle, wordplay

What word can be attached at the beginning or end of these words to make different words?

- Form
- Line
- Mark
- Wet
- Main
- Grass

Hint:

> The word is 4 letters long.

Comment: This same type of puzzle is in the brain games book

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word is:

> **LAND**

We can make the words:

> **land**form, **land**line, **land**mark, wet**land**, main**land**, grass**land**

Comment: The number of the beast as your rep number needs to be terminated for good. $(+1)$

Answer (score 0):

## Partial answer:

> **PLOT** / **PLAT**.

Here the following working words:

> **PLAT**FORM

> The word *subplot* is an actual word, so MAIN**PLOT** is a sketchy attempt of mine.

> **PLOT**LINE

> GRASS**PLOT** (*Microsoft Word* does not consider this a word, however.)